# Why are there two bin folders in Mingw port of gcc builds?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I recently tried to download  the latest version of gcc for Windows. When I downloaded the latest version from this link (the dwarf version) : [x32-4.8.0-release-posix-dwarf-rev1.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-posix/dwarf/) I noticed there are two bin directories.

```
1.bin
2.i686-w64-mingw32\bin
```

What's the difference between these two folders and which one should I introduce to the IDE (e.g CodeBlocks). Why in first place there are two folders already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the way GCC/binutils works. The executables in the `<target>\bin` subdirectory are for internal use by the compiler only. This should never be in `PATH`.

The executables in the toplevel `bin` directory are the ones you need to use, which in turn call the real compilers and may call the executables in the subdirectory.

I agree it is silly for it to be this way, but I see no way of this being changed in the near or far future.

Comment: Thank you very muchL:) I just noticed that there are two include folders as well! 
1.include  and 
2.i686-w64-mingw32\include ,
 which the second one contains lots of header files (standard one included ) while the first one only has several header files.Which one should i use in Path var ?

Comment: You don't need to add any to any environment variable. GCC knows to look in those directories so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

The bin folder is the one I use for setting up an IDE.
I do not know why there are 2 folders,the path of the second bin folder seems like a cross-compiler to me.